# How to make sticky element scrollable?

Tags: css

I have a sticky navbar that is vertical but when the screen is too small I want it to be scrollable. Now I can only get to see the bottom categories in navBar only when I scroll to the bottom of the page and then it scrolls.

[image: Nav Bar on big screen]

[image: Nav bar on small screen]

On the second photo I'd like it be scrollable when o hover over it with my mouse.
I've tried:

- Setting a height to it but the categories change so the height is changes.
- Setting height to fit content
- Setting max-height to max-content

Comment: set the navbar to a ´max-height: 100vh;` which will make its height a maximum of the browser windo height. Then use `overflow-y: auto;` to give it an overflwo ability with scrollbar.

Comment: @tacoshy Thank you it worked, put it as an answer and I'll mark it is the correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a specific code sample I just give you a "random code sample" mimicing the navbar. You have to implement the code yourself.

1. Add a `max-height: 100vh;` to the navbar. This will limit the navbars height to the height of the browser window height.
2. Allow a vertical overflow and scrollbar by using `overflow-y: auto;` on the navbar. In combination with the max height, it allows an overflow of the navbar itself instead of resizing the height.

```css
nav {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}





/* for styling purpose only */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 150px;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  <a href="#">Link 7</a>
  <a href="#">Link 8</a>
  <a href="#">Link 9</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This wont work if the element is not positioned exactly on the edges of the screen. For example if the sticky element is 200px to the bottom, max-height: 100vh will still overflow the screen

Comment: which would be a completely different case and task as asked by the OP.